# Is the limit of the cross product of two functions equal to the cross product of the limits?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, vector-spaces, continuity, cross-product

From p. 85 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, we know the limit at a given point of the dot product of two functions mapping into $\mathbb{R^k}$ is the dot product of the limits at that point of each of the individual functions. What about the limit of the cross product of two such functions? Would it be the cross product of the limits of the individual functions?

Comment: Can you express the cross product using field operations only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, obviously, since the cross product is given by polynomials, and polynomials are continuous functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it really necessary to say "obviously" here though? If I knew the answer I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to sound rude! What I meant was just that it's nothing deep – it's obvious once you look at it from the right angle. But there's nothing strange about needing a bit of help to find the right angle. That happens to all of us!